# How to customise the x-axis line in ggplot2 so that it is broken according to factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to replicate the x-axis design of a figure I have seen. Is it possible to use ggplot2 to recreate the a-axis?

I have tried to use the `lemon` package, but this didn't quite replicate the axis as I wanted.

I want the x-axis to look like the image on the left in this

[image]

EDIT

Apologies for any confusion, I have now edited in some example data and code as requested.

tidy_data:

```
Replicate Group Time
1   Control 0.09997222
2   Control 0.04466667
3   Control 0.08608333
4   Control 0.10712500
5   Control 0.11410000
6   Control 0.69333333
7   Control 0.42383333
8   Control 0.06105556
9   Control 0.08676667
1   Treatment   0.13700000
2   Treatment   0.02983333
3   Treatment   0.49608333
4   Treatment   0.97858333
5   Treatment   0.70900000
6   Treatment   0.18683333
7   Treatment   0.45283333
8   Treatment   1.30220833
9   Treatment   1.39908333
```

results_tbl:

```
mean_time   sem         upper_sem   lower_sem   treatment
0.1534459   0.03681368  0.1902596   0.1166323   Control
0.8238021   0.15860139  0.9824035   0.6652007   Treatment
```

Plot Code:

```
figure = ggplot() +
    geom_quasirandom(
      data = tidy_data,
      aes(x = Group, y = Time, colour = Replicate),
      size = 5,
      varwidth = TRUE
    ) +
    geom_point(
      data = results_tbl,
      aes(x = treatment, y = mean_time),
      colour = "black",
      size = 4
    ) +
    geom_errorbar(
      data = results_tbl,
      aes(x = treatment, ymin = lower_sem, ymax = upper_sem),
      alpha = 1,
      size = 0.1,
      width = 0.1,
      colour = "black"
    ) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks()) +
    labs(x = "", y = "Mean time spent in zone ± SE (mins)") +
    theme_cowplot(font_size = 16, line_size = 1) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 2))
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. What about the axis do you want to replicate?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I like the design of the x-axis in the left-hand image above (i.e. it isn't a solid line for the the entire length of the x-axis) and want to replicate it using ggplot. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a dataset and some plotting code with an example plot, along with the code you used from the **lemon** package (I'm guessing you were trying out `coord_capped()`?).  That will help folks test things out.

Comment: I have now edited the original post to include the requested content. I did not include any code from the `lemon` package as it isn't possible to use it for what I want to achieve. Thanks.